# Is double exclamation sign(!!) is equal to Boolean constructor in JS?

Tags: javascript

I start learning javascript, and found some interesting thing

I just can't find any difference between !! and Boolean, but the speed performance seems to be much better with !!

Comment: `!!` is just two `!` operators.  It does the `!` operation on whatever variable you give it, then it does `!` again on the result.

Comment: You can confirm in the ECMAScript Language Specification for [! unary operator](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.4.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!!` and `Boolean(...)` are *functionally* equal. But you should probably use the Boolean constructor in most situations because it is easier to understand by most people, even by beginners.